# In Scenekit how to split one SCNNode into many nodes?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I trying to load a .obj file. how ever after loaded, secenekit only generate one node with a huge geometry which has many submeshes. Anyone has idea how to split this huge node into many nodes, each node owns one submesh form the original node? As I need to apply different physic on them. Thanks in advance.

I have tried following approach:

1. manually parse the .obj file. this works but eat up too much memory
2. after load the file, I get the huge node. then I do

   ```
           let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: rootNode.geometry!.geometrySources, elements: [rootNode.geometry!.geometryElementAtIndex(count)])
           geometry.firstMaterial = rootNode.geometry!.materials[count]
           let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
   ```

for each mesh (get from .obj file)
this also work, but take a long time for rendering, I guess is because I copy the whole source for each node.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have already found a couple of approaches that give you correct results, but they take too long to do at run time. So run with those, but do it in advance.

Run your manual OBJ parse, or your per-element geometry retrieval, in an auxiliary program. Archive that result to an `SCNScene` (or maybe `SCNNodes`). Embed the archive/archives in your public project. Unarchiving a .SCN file will be much faster than parsing and instantiating a big OBJ file.

Here's a function to archive a scene to a file. You can then embed the file in your project and open it the way the space ship is opened in the template code, or use the Xcode Scene Editor to tweak it.

```
func archiveToFile(fileName: String) -> Bool {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(gameView!.scene!)

    // Save data to file
    let DocumentDirURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)

    let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName).URLByAppendingPathExtension("scn")
    print("FilePath:", fileURL.path)

    if (!data.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true)) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Hi Hal, thanks very much for your suggestion. This sounds like a good idea, but it also looks like I need to spend quite a lot of time to write a converter. anyway will try on this if got time. Thanks.

Comment: I thought you had already written the conversion code? From there, add an archive step and you're done.

Comment: Hi Hal, what I have done is just read the data from the .obj file and using sceneKit API to create nodes according to those data. To pre-generate the .scn file, I think I need more knowledge about the format of .scn file. Do you have any idea how to generate a .scn file by code? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mal, thanks for your update, there are two issues stop this to work for me. 1, I cannot use Xcode to pre-process the data file as this step is done by the server and the server is not a mac server. 2. for some large files, it will eat up all the memory before the construction is done and crash the app.

Comment: Your preprocessor program can run on a Mac, even as a command line program. It doesn't need to run on an iOS sim or device. Your non-Mac server just needs a way to transfer files to and from the Mac doing the conversion. It sounds like you're very close on this; keep going methodically and don't try to solve the whole thing at once.